# Parsing Array value as props in Vue.JS

Tags: javascript, vue.js, v-for, vue-props

I have the following component which are used for "select" option in parent:

```
<template>
  <label class="label" for="select">{{ label }}</label>
  <select class="form-control form-control" v-bind:name="name" id="select">
    <option v-bind:options="options" v-for="(value, index) in options" :key="index">{{ value.objectValue }}</option>
  </select>
</template>


export default {
  name: "Select",
  props: {
    label: String,
    options: Array,
    name: String,
    objectValue: String
  }
}
```

The array I parse consist of objects and looks like this:

```
let array = [{name: valueOne}, {name: valueTwo}]
```

My problem is when I pass the prop "objectValue" it does not select it. This is how I use the component:

```
<Select label="Select country" objectValue="name" v-bind:options="array"/>
```

So I get a blank array, but with the correct amount of values. So the problem should be around the parsing of the "name" value from objectValue props.

Answer (score 0):

The `select` needs a [`v-model`](https://v3.vuejs.org/api/directives.html#v-model) with an intial value.

1. Declare a data property (named `selectedOption`), and bind `<select>.v-model` to it:

   ```html
   <template>
     <select v-model="selectedOption">...</select>
   </template>

   <script>
   export default {
     data() {
       return {
         selectedOption: null
       }
     }
   }
   </script>
   ```
2. Add a [watcher](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/computed.html#watchers) on `objectValue` that copies the new value to `selectedOption`:

   ```js
   export default {
     watch: {
       objectValue: {
         handler(newValue) {
           this.selectedOption = newValue
         },
         immediate: true,
       },
     }
   }
   ```

[demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/initial-value-for-select-in-vue-3-0kodh?file=/src/components/MySelect.vue)